# jupyter notebook R cell very slow to execute

Tags: r, jupyter-notebook

I'm testing jupyter notebook for R and Python (in order to use one unique tool for both langage instead of Rstudio and spyder now).
I ported a small Python code in a first notebook and it runs fast.
BUT then i tested a very small R notebook and the cell execute very slowly.
cell 1

```
 library(tidyverse)
    library(nycflights13)
    ## Chargement des trois tables
    data(flights)
    data(airports)
    data(airlines)
```

cell 2

```
slice(airports, 345)
```

cell 3

```
filter(flights, month == 1)
```

cell 1 execute quickly but not cell 2 or cell 3 (they take at least 10 seconds).
NB : variable inspector is **not** activated.
Is there a way to execute R cells more quickly? Otherwise I will stick to Rstudio.

Yours sincerely
Loïc

Comment: I did the first tests with chrome and the results were terrible. But I just tested on firefox and everythings works fine : when I run all cells (the 3 R cell) I take roughly 1s in total. I don't undestand why there is such a difference between Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: What happens if you restart the kernel and use Firefox. Is it slow then?